# Which memory (heap or stack) should I use to allocate a large memory like 100MB?

Tags: arrays, memory, heap-memory, allocation, stack-memory

I need a very large array (100MB) and I can allocate memory both on heap and stack. Where should I allocate the memory for the array and why?

```
    int a[10];
    int* a = new int[10];
```

How should I allocate the memory?

Comment: Chances are the program will *crash* when attempting to allocate “100MB on the stack”. (The default on windows is 1MB, and 8MB on linux..)

Answer (score 2):

The stack is generally more limited than the heap so, if those were your only two choices, I'd opt for the heap<sup>(a)</sup>.

Just keep in mind 100M may be a lot of data, depending on the platform you're running on. If you *still* hit limits when using the heap (either *hard* limits or just issues related to using that much memory), you may want to consider some form of "paging", where you don't have to have the entire structure in memory at the same time.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Under Linux, for example, I believe 8M may be the default stack size. And linking under Windows normally sets the size to 1M. I think that, in both cases, you can change this but you have to do so  *explicitly.* Otherwise, with those defaults (assuming I'm not remembering incorrectly), having a *single* stack frame needing 100M is likely to cause issues :-)